# Handling File(.xlsx) as a response of Rest API in flutter and download the same

Tags: flutter, dart

In my App, I am hitting a REST Api and as response api returns a File (.xlsx) how to handle the file response in flutter and also I want that file gets downloaded in the device, How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dio flutter package .  [Flutter Dio Pub](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) 
And Here the details code [dio download code](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/download.dart)

```
Future download1(Dio dio, String url, savePath) async {
    CancelToken cancelToken = CancelToken();
    try {
      await dio.download(url, savePath,
          onReceiveProgress: showDownloadProgress, cancelToken: cancelToken);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_downloader. Don't forget to do platform configurations.

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your download link',
  savedDir: 'the path of directory where you want to save downloaded files',
);
```

I hope this helps, in case of any doubts please comment. *If this answer helps you then please accept and up-vote it.*

Comment: Hey Kalpesh, Thanks for answer, I have a doubt what I have to add it in url part as I am hitting an api with some req parameters, and what will be my json header,I am doing like this , final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', "token": "$token"};
    reqFormat['id'] ="1";   String jsonBody = json.encode(reqFormat);
    final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      end_point_url,
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonBody,
      encoding: encoding,
    ); if the result is json response I have it in a response.body

Comment: Download Url = http(s)://Server:Port/path?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2